# How to calculate flight speed of evaporated metal atoms?

Tags: temperature, velocity, metals, evaporation

Suppose a metal is heated in vacuum to its melting/sublimation point such that [evaporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporation_(deposition)) is significant. How to estimate the metal atoms velocity after they detach (evaporate) from the bulk?

Comment: As a rough approximation, you can pretend that the vapor is an ideal gas in equilibrium and use the [kinetic theory of gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases#Speed_of_molecules) to estimate the mean kinetic energy of the molecules. The metal molecules will be single atoms or small clusters of atoms, so you can then find estimates of the mean speed for various sized clusters.

Comment: @PM2Ring If for example I take boiling point of 3240K (gold, M=197 g/mol) then $v=\sqrt{3RT/M}=640 \mathrm{m s^{-1}}$. Does it make sense?

Comment: That looks ok to me. I get 640.4969 ms$^{-1}$. Bear in mind that's the RMS speed, the mean speed is a little lower, and the most probable speed lower still, around 522ms$^{-1}$. See the hyperphysics [Molecular Speed Calculator](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/kintem.html#c4).

Comment: @PM2Ring the calculation may be correct but how accurate is this approximation? Does 600 m/s really makes sense..? That's a pretty massive bombardment, no?

Comment: It _is_ just a rough approximation because your system is neither in equilibrium nor an ideal gas, but it makes sense to me. Use the calculator and check the speed of air molecules at room temperature, or water molecules at 100°C. Or consider that speed of light molecules like hydrogen & helium in the upper atmosphere exceeds escape velocity. Sure gold is a lot heavier than air or water, but your gold vapor is also a lot hotter. And check out the speeds you get for clusters of say, 2 to 20 atoms.

Comment: @PM2Ring yeah I compared. But does it make sense to use the boiling temperature in the equation, if the metal overall is close to its melting temperature?

Comment: Oops. I forgot that in your question you were asking about behaviour  just above the metal's melting point. You need to use the actual temperature! So using 1064°C I get 411ms$^{-1}$ as the RMS speed.